# Second Monitor blue tones turns to purple [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: dual-boot, hdmi, colors, external-monitor, vga

i'm currently using dual boot with Windows 10  and Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop, and i found a problem with my second screen that (when i'm on ubuntu) turns all the blue tones into a purple-ish tone. On the main screen (my laptop) the colours are ok, but on the second monitor it appears to not like the blue colour at all.

I've already checked the cable (tried HDMI and VGA) and didn't solved the issue. And what  bothers me the most is that on windows it works amazingly, no problems at all.

I don't know if there's a color profile problem, or some driver that is included on windows and not on ubuntu, but this problem really annoys me.

Anyway, hope someone could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. It also could be a hardware issue. You do not say how the monitor is attached to the computer. Is it a port on the computer if so what port? Is it some kind of adapter device?

Comment: Its now pluged with a VGA Connector, but i also tried HDMI and both got me the same result. I also used the same cables on other computers and other monitors and they worked properly on them...

Comment: Turn off color settings, it should fix that.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry everybody, the problem i was facing is just different hardware on each screen, one was LCD and the other was LED or something like that (different). Thanks for the help anyway.